# Pygame window freezes and stop responding, how could I fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am creating a game but I am having a problem with my button class for my gui. There are no compile errors and no runtime errors either. The only problem is that on run it immediately freezes the pygame window. I don't know how to solve this.

I've tried fiddling around with the callback function (which I removed entirely) and with the update and draw loop as well but nothing seems to work.

Python 3.7.0 and Pygame 1.9.4

Button Class:

```
import sys
import time
import pygame
pygame.init()

class button:
    def __init__(self, txt, location, bg=(255,255,255),fg=(0,0,0),size=(80,30),font_name="Times New Roman",font_size=16):
        #bg is the colour of the button
        #fg is the colour of the text
        #location refers to the center points of the button
        self.colour = bg
        self.bg = bg
        self.fg = fg
        self.size = size
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(font_name,font_size)
        self.txt = txt
        self.txt_surf = self.font.render(self.txt, 1, self.fg)
        self.txt_rect = self.txt_surf.get_rect(center=[s//2 for s in self.size])
        self.surface = pygame.surface.Surface(size)
        self.rect = self.surface.get_rect(center=location)
    def mouseover(self):
        self.bg = self.colour
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            self.bg = (200,200,200)
    def draw(self, screen):
        self.mouseover()
        self.surface.fill(self.bg)
        self.surface.blit(self.txt_surf, self.txt_rect)
        screen.blit(self.surface, self.rect)
```

Actual update/draw loop

```
import gui
import pygame
import sys
import time
import win32api
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
button1 = gui.button("No", (200,200))
intro = True
while intro:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    button1.draw(screen)
    if win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) == -127 or win32api.GetKeyState(0x01) == -128:
        if button1.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            intro = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(20)
```

I really just want the window to stop freezing up on run and to actually have a button press work. What it should do is immediately quit the application when you press the button in the middle. Not actually do that though.

Answer (score 2):

You have to let pygame process the events in the event queue by calling `pygame.event.get` (or `pygame.event.pump`, but you should stick to use `get`).

Otherwise, the queue will fill up and new events will be dropped. This includes internal events that tell your OS to draw the window etc, so your window will freeze.

Also, there's no reason to use `win32api` to get the state of the keyboard (you can use `pygame.key.get_pressed` instead), but that's another topic.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem though, it will draw to the screen and you can see the button and the text, the problem is after drawing, it'll freeze. Edit: Nvm, you were right. Goddamn, I never knew

Comment: @ShawnHu The answer is absolutely correct. You're code has no event handling, that's why the window freezes! Note, the message loop of the windows API needs the to be processed. That happens when the events are handled.